# Looping through pandas dataframe to get highest possible total score of football players with unique clubs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, logic

I have a dataframe with football players with their *team name, position *and* total score* based on a bunch of factors during the games they played. I want to create a team with the highest total score for different line-ups (4-3-3, 4-4-2, etc.) but the clubs can only occur for 1 player in that team. So if I got a goalkeeper from club X then I can't have a defender from club X. Right now I am able to create a team for a 4-3-3 line-up (4 defenders, 3 midfielders, 3 attackers) but there are duplicate teams in there. ( see screenshot ). Also, if the total scores of 2 players are equal then the minutes_played should make the difference. Does anyone have an idea on how to start building this logic?

***(I am not sure if this post is clear enough and acceptable for stackoverflow. If not, please tell me how to improve or what to provide to make it acceptable)***

All help is highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I am having difficulties matching the title of your question to the description. Could you provide a specific example based on the given screenshot, what are the inputs , what is the expected output etc.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy sure! the input is a dataframe of players with the information provided in the screenshot. the desired output would be the same as the output shown in the screenshot but then without duplicate team_names. So every team can only have 1 player in the output team. The total score of the team should be the highest possible with all the players considered but of course every role with the specified amount ( example: 4-3-3, 4 defenders, 3 midfielders, 3 attackers ) The title is about looping because I expect that looping is needed to get to the desired result.

Comment: correct me if im wrong...  SO ,now do have to created one team best team or different teams with best player with every team being presented only once ? ( no repetition ? ) or select the best members from different teams and combine into one or multiple teams with each one having their one best player irrespective of their position ( goalkeeper or defender ?) .... a good explanation and your requirement in simple words would be helpful for a person like me who has a limited knowledge on football ;)

Comment: @daksh I can understand that it is confusing :p, So, I would like to have 1! team (let's call it the dream team) which is made up with players from all teams in a competition. Every team in the competition can only have 1 player from them in that dreamteam. I want the highest possible total score of the dream team. Just like in the screenshot but without the duplicate teams. ( since every club can only provide 1 player )

Answer (score 0):

According to the details and my understanding , I have 2 Assumptions for the different ways to create the best score team

The team needs to have **4** defenders , **3** mid-fielder , **3** attackers ( 4-3-3 )

**ASSUMPTION 1 to create team**

all the players of the new team should be from different and unique team ( **no 2 teams can be same from the competitive teams** )

**i.e.** no two player can be from the same team therefore there needs to be at-least **10** unique teams

**ASSUMPTION 2 to create team**

the players for different roles of the new team should be from different and unique team but for the same role can be from the same team ( this assumption was based on the repetition condition provided in the question )

**i.e.** no two player can be from the same team for different roles but can be there for the same role .. therefore there needs to be at-least **3** unique teams

*for example :*
out of **4** defenders there can be more than **1** player from the same team **but** out of **4** defenders and **3** mid-fielders there cannot be a player from the same team i.e. either defenders or mid-fielder can have the player but not both

**SOLUTIONS**

*FOR ASSUMPTION 1*

store the 10 team-name in linear-array

you can create **3 2d arrays AND 1 multi-dimensional (3d) arrays**

- type of array : **2d** Array ( 2 dimensional to store both the player-name and his/her team-name )
- number of arrays : **3** ( 1 for defenders , 1 for mid-fielder , 1 for attackers )
- **team_array** -stores competitive teams name and their players , scores and minutes played *( ex:- team_array[10][11][5] )*
- **d_array** - stores defenders data *( ex :- d_array[4][2] )*
- **m_array** - stores mid-fielders data *( ex :- m_array[3][2] )*
- **a_array** - stores attackers data *( ex :- m_array[3][2] )*

now using for-loop ( **you can use ANY loop** but my fav is for-loop :) )

- ITTERATE through every index of the **team_array**
- and using **if decision control statement** check if the team is already present in the final team
- if not present then check for the role among the members of the team for example defenders
- if defender then check the highest score among the defenders
- then if high score is less than the current player's high score then make the
  current player highest scored player
- if both are same then make changes according to the minutes played
- end of all the loops add the best player details to **d_array** which where stored in a variable

  ```
  high_score=0

  high_time=0

  con=false

  d_c=0

  player_det=["xxx","xxx"]

  for i in range(10):                       //loop for team

   for j in range(11):                    // loop for player

     for k in range(4):      // -----------> LINE 69

      if d_array[k][1] == team_array[i][j][4]  // if player from same team already exists 
        // pre assign d_array with garbage value with wont clash with the original data

         con=true 
         break
     if con != true:          // ------------> LINE 420
        for k in range(3):
           if m_array[k][1]  == team_array[i][j][4] || a_array[k][1]  == team_array[i][j][4] :
             con=true
             break

     if con != true:

       if team_array[i][j][5] == "defender":  // condition for only checking defenders

         if team_array[i][j][0] > high_score: // condition for high score player

            high_score=team_array[i][j][0]  

            high_time=team_array[i][j][1]

            player_det[0]=team_array[i][j][2]

            player_det[1]=team_array[i][j][3]

        elif team_array[i][j][0] == high_score: //condition if high score is equal for two players

           if high_time < team_array[i][j][1]

              high_time=team_array[i][j][1]

              player_det[0]=team_array[i][j][2]

              player_det[1]=team_array[i][j][3]

   d_array[d_c++][0]=player_det[0]
   d_array[d_c++][1]=player_det[1]
  ```

**do this for every player role and make changes accordingly**

- after doing this for every player role
- add the required parts ( player-name, team-name ...etc depending on your requirement ) from every array (i.e. **d_array** .. etc) to a final array

*FOR ASSUMPTION 2*

**its the same code but remove the lines from *line 69 to line 420* from the above code**

*the above code may have few minute syntax and logical errors :)*

**HOPE THIS IS WHAT YOU WERE LOOKING FOR**

***FEEL FREE TO ASK ANYTHING RELATED TO THE SOLUTION ;)***

**PS :** running short of time so you will have to complete the rest of code